# Blazor Server-side app Android and IOS mode

Tags: android, ios, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am building a Server-side Blazor web application on localhost for now.

I want to test my web app on android and IOS devices but I cannot seem to find the solution.

I have tried connecting to the same network via wifi and have my IP address with :port but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give ngrok a go, this would allow you to map your localhost and port to a public web address.

There are a bunch of details here:

https://ngrok.com/